# Running Evosuite with DSE

Tags: evosuite

I am using Evosuite in Linux from the command line.

According to the articles about Evosuite, there is an option to combine Evosuite with Dynamic Symbolic Execution (DSE)!

Haw can this be set from the command line? Is there any parameter to enable/disable DSE?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

DSE is currently disabled, as its code is going through a major refactoring and fixing, which is not complete yet, as far as version 0.2.0 :(